# Tabs in fullscreen Chrome/Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, browser, fullscreen, tabs

I love Chrome and Chromium, but when I go full screen, I can't get to my other tabs anymore, which I can with Firefox. So my questions are:

Am I alone or is this universal?

Is there a fix?

Is there some useful keyboard shortcut to switch tabs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think full screen is designed for getting more space, so tabs do not appear in full screen.

Shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Next Tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Previous Tab
- <kbd>F11</kbd>: Enter/Leave Full screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: New Tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>: Close Tab

Comment: We know  full screen is designed for getting more space. Point is, Firefox in fullscreen shows tabs, addressbar, and bookmarks on hover. Full browser experience even in fullscreen mode. Chrome deprives full-screen users of the full browser experience-- firefox does not.

Comment: Ctrl+T wont focus on google search input :(
in fact google search wont work at all in full screen

Comment: `Cmd+Shift+f` enters fullscreen with tabs on Mac, I wish I could have the same in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know for Version 77, there are two extensions can take the tabs back:

1. Tab Revolution
2. tabtiles